# Apache/Varinish redirecting example.com/folder to example.com:8080/folder/

Tags: apache, varnish

I'm having an issue on this new VPS I'm setting up. I've set up Apache/Varnish but when I try to access a folder on the domain, such as `example.com/whatever` it is redirecting to `example.com:8080/whatever/` and I'm getting a page not available. However when I access `example.com/whatever/` with a trailing `/` at the end everything works fine. I'm pretty new to Varnish so any help troubleshooting would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have rewrite rule in Apache to append the missing trailing slash on URLs and it is using the Apache host and port for the `Location:` response header. Either move that logic into Varnish or modify it to not use the port in Apache.